# Can't make Twitter search with React and Twit

Tags: reactjs, twitter

I am trying to use Twit library on codesandbox.io . I added dependency Twit and followed documentation. Console returns nothing. 
In the code below I replaced actual keys with ###

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Twit from "twit";

import "./styles.css";

/* I included ### instead of secrets */
const user = new Twit({
  consumer_key: "###",
  consumer_secret: "###",
  access_token: "###",
  access_token_secret: "###"
});

user.get("search/tweets", { q: "banana", count: 100 }, function(
 err,data,response) {
    console.log(data);
 });
```

Comment: You need to use actual key provided by the twitter. If you hook the error callback, then you may see the error.

Comment: I do use the actual key, I just replaced it here with ###

Answer (score 0):

If I replace

```
import Twit from "twit";
```

with

```
var Twit = require('twit');
```

I get your code to working.
I'm sorry I can't explain why.